# as.Date function giving incorrect year

Tags: r, date, as.date

```
as.Date('28/3/2021', '%d/%m/%y')
```

gives output:

```
[1] "2020-03-28"
```

How do I write the code to ensure the year is correct i.e. 2021, not 2020?

Comment: Fairly common error. (And a multiply duplicated question on SO.)Should have been "%Y" rather than "%y". The reaon it was off by one year was that it ignore anything beyond the 8 characters implied by that format spec.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution + explanation:

```
> # %Y is used for 4 digit numbers
> 
> as.Date('28/3/2021', '%d/%m/%Y')
[1] "2021-03-28"
> 
> # while %y for 2 digits
> 
> as.Date('28/3/21', '%d/%m/%y')
[1] "2021-03-28"
>
```